# HDFS nodes OOM too many files?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

We have an HDFS cluster with five nodes. Too often when writing new files to the file system we get either "Not enough replicas" error or following:

```
2016-05-29 13:30:03,972 [Thread-486536] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient - Exception in createBlockOutputStream
java.io.IOException: Got error, status message , ack with firstBadLink as 10.100.1.22:50010
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.DataTransferProtoUtil.checkBlockOpStatus(DataTransferProtoUtil.java:142) ~[hadoop-hdfs-2.7.1.jar!/:na]
...
2016-05-29 13:30:03,972 [Thread-486536] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient - Abandoning BP-1195099512-10.100.1.21-1454597789659:blk_1085523876_11792285
2016-05-29 13:30:03,977 [Thread-486536] INFO  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient - Excluding datanode DatanodeInfoWithStorage[10.100.1.22:50010,DS-2f34af8d-234a-4036-a810-908c3b2bd9cf,DISK]
2016-05-29 13:30:04,003 [pool-1272-thread-3] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient - Slow waitForAckedSeqno took 65098ms (threshold=30000ms)
```

We also experience a lot of these, which seems to be when big GC'ing occurs.

```
 [pool-9-thread-23] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient - Slow waitForAckedSeqno took 34607ms (threshold=30000ms)
 [pool-9-thread-30] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient - Slow waitForAckedSeqno took 34339ms (threshold=30000ms)
 [pool-9-thread-5] WARN  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient - Slow waitForAckedSeqno took 34593ms (threshold=30000ms)
```

The filesystem holds 6.5 million small (4-20 kB) files and the nodes goes down with OOM when we write new files. New files are always written in batches and a batch can be a few hundred thousands.

The nodes have a lot of RAM at the moment to not OOM, 4 GB for name node and 3 GB for data nodes.

Is this really expected behavior? Why are the nodes eating such a uge amount of RAM?

I want to increase the number of nodes to see if we can run with more strict mem settings, like 1024 MB instead. Possible?

EDIT: We see a lot of GC happening and when the GC occurs nodes are not responding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end the problem was the underlying storage system that failed. Moved the cluster to HW rack, added a second name node, periodically archive used files into HAR filesystems and HDFS is a happy panda.

If you ever see similar problems and your platform is based on any kind of virtualization. Move away from virtual mumbo jumbo immediately.

Comment: Please what is the size of MTU 1500 or 9000?
because some documentation recommend the use  9000 on your network interfaces